# OpneGL ES Program on Android not emulating and giving these errors

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

[2013-04-14 12:05:12 - Cube3D] ------------------------------

[2013-04-14 12:05:12 - Cube3D] Android Launch!

[2013-04-14 12:05:12 - Cube3D] adb is running normally.

[2013-04-14 12:05:12 - Cube3D] Performing com.example.myfirst3dcube.Cube3D activity launch

[2013-04-14 12:05:12 - Cube3D] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_3_7_FWVGA_slider'

[2013-04-14 12:05:12 - Cube3D] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_3_7_FWVGA_slider'

[2013-04-14 12:06:53 - Cube3D] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-04-14 12:06:53 - Cube3D] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

[2013-04-14 12:07:22 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005

[2013-04-14 12:07:22 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

[2013-04-14 12:07:22 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!

[2013-04-14 12:07:22 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!

[2013-04-14 12:07:22 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

[2013-04-14 12:07:22 - Emulator] 
[2013-04-14 12:08:34 - Cube3D] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.myfirst3dcube.Cube3D activity launch'!

Plz guide me regarding resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the the parameters for the emulator, please chech this link:

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-emulator-now-supports-native-opengl-es2-0/

or this

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Even if it works on the older versions is software rendered and it will be very slow, if it works at all that is, however the new version never tried but since is hardware accelerated probably is lot faster(first link).

Comment: No it didn't find a help to my problem.